# (solved) Display all Entityform submission to visitors

Tags: entities

I build up a form using Entityform.
Finally I want that every visitor (registered or not) can see trough all submissions. How can i do that? If i create a View under Structure -> Views -> Entityforms (A list of all entityforms submissions), the System goves me a Error:

> Fehlermeldung
>   Views cannot create normal menu items for paths with a % in them.

How should the right path be?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The `%` character indicates a wild-card, which can't be used in a normal menu item. If you remove that wildcard character from the path, it will work

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Clive, but if I do this and provide a menu link on "/entityform-submissions/submissions/list" (instead of /entityform-submissions/submissions/%/list) it tells me that the page could not be found.

Comment: Did you clean cache after you changed the path?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Dont know what I'm doing wrong here :/

Comment: `%` should work with views path. You should try `entityform-submissions/submissions/1/list` instead of `entiatyform-submissions/submissions/%/list` in the address  bar. Have you add any contextual filter in your view?